# Having issues connecting to my Amplify Backend on my javascript file

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-amplify

I have a non React Javascript file that attached as a module on an HTML script.

I have set up Amplify to host my website and all the frontend stuff looks great, I have attempted to use the Amplify backend however I cannot get my amplify to connect.

I have created my data structures, as well as installed the Amplify CLI in my root directory.

I have pulled my project,

then I tried to go forward with the documentation

```
import { DataStore } from '@aws-amplify/datastore';
import { Metadata } from './src/models';

const models = DataStore.query(Metadata);
console.log(models);
```

I was met with this error: Failed to resolve module specifier "@aws-amplify/datastore". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

I tried adding this:

```
import { Amplify } from "aws-amplify";
import awsconfig from './aws-exports';
Amplify.configure(awsconfig);
```

but similarly it says it cannot find aws-amplify.

I did npm init, and then npm i aws-amplify, and still nothing.

I tried all the documentation, but nothing is working.